# How do I access axios response promise and use it on my webpage?

Tags: reactjs, get, promise, response, axios

How do I gain acceess to promises so that I can use for example the bitcoin price on my website?

```
axios.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?convert=EUR&limit=10')
  .then(function(response){
    console.log(response.data[0].price_usd); 
  });
```

Here is a codepen with a sample of the code.

https://codepen.io/albin996/pen/LzLZYX?editors=1112

Answer (score 0):

We should start by noting that external requests should be carefully handled in React so the actual reactivity works well keeping its performance. That's why we're going to create a class to holds this logic in a organized way.

```javascript
const URL = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/convert=EUR&limit=10';

// Our component now is a full class
class BitcoinDisplay extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Start with no response available
    this.state = {response: false}; 
  }

  // Waits the component to be rendered before calling API
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(URL).then(response => {
        // Updates the state with the response
        this.setState({ response })
    });
  }

  // Renders the component with the available data
  render() {
    if(!this.state.response) {
      // Show a loading state because data may not be available yet
      return 'Loading data...'; 
    } else {
      return (<h1>{response.data[0].price_usd}</h1>);
    }
  }
}
```

Then, you render it inside the DOM.

```javascript
ReactDOM.render(BitcoinDisplay, document.getElementById('app'));
```